# R mapply with named arguments

Tags: r

One fear I have when using `mapply` in R is that I may mess up the order of arguments & hence unconsciously generate garbage results.

```
mydata<-data.frame(Temperature=foobar,Pressure=foobar2)
myfunction<-function(P,T)
{
....
}
mapply(FUN = myfunction,mydata$Temperature,mydata$Pressure)
```

Is there a way to utilize named arguments to avoid this sort of error via mapply?

Comment: @akrun Exactly! Thanks. If you post as an answer I can accept it. I'm embarrassed, Such an obvious answer in hindsight. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to match the function arguments, name the arguments for `Map/mapply` with the arguments of the function

```
mapply(FUN = myfunction,T=mydata$Temperature,P=mydata$Pressure)
```

We can apply the function directly instead of `mapply` though (based on the example provided below in my post)

```
do.call(myfunction, unname(mydata[2:1]))
```

#### data

```
mydata <- data.frame(Temperature = 1:5, Pressure = 16:20)
myfunction <- function(P, T) {P*5 + T*10}
```